# NS2-Modification of protocol

Tags: c++, ns2

I want to count the number of packets being sent from a node in NS2 at run time. That for I would like to make changes in AODV protocol using C++. Could someone help me how to proceed?

Comment: Tried editing the recv() function to count the number of packets being received and forward() function in aodv.cc to count the number of packets being sent. I am not able to identify from which node the packet came and to which node the packet being forwarded. I want to know the count for calculating trust value on each node and find  malicious one. Can you please help me how to get and proceed. What about using promiscuous mode in AODV. I am very new to all these. Thank you in advance.